# How do you generate a URL with custom variables on each product page?

Tags: shopify

I need to generate a URL link on each product page. Each URL needs to contain custom variables specific to that product.

Like so : www.example.com/{{keywords}}/{{productID}}

My understanding is that any custom variables must be saved as metaTags. 
My logic to generate the URL is as follows

1. Create an Embedded App.
2. Display a dropdown list containing all products.
3. Display input fields for the user to populate with the text for "keywords" and "productID"
4. Save this information as Meta Tags so it can be accessible within the Liquid templeting.

Example Mockup of Embedded App : https://imgur.com/D9Grv4m
Example Mockup of Generated URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LfXN.jpg

How do I solve the following issues?

1. How do i save "keywords" and "productID" variables for each individual product.
2. How do I generate a URL with these variables and populate them on each product page?(I can do it manually through editing the theme but there has to be a way to do this programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate an URL like:

```
www.example.com/{{keywords}}/{{productID}}
```

With Shopify you instead use

```
www.example.com/products/product-handle
```

And on that product page, you can do as you please with the product ID, and any metafields you choose to maintain and create.

Comment: How can I reach you? I have a small off-topic query I need a direction on.